# What's wrong with my graphics drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

I apologize if this is a repeat post. I wasn't sure how to search for it. I'm having a problem with my graphics on Ubuntu 12.03.4. I currently have 2 monitors (DVI and HDMI) and 6 workspaces (3 wide x 2 tall) and whenever I go from any of my workspaces to the top-left workspace, I was getting two strange graphical glitches: (1) The 3x2 workspace window wouldn't remain on the screen until I did something to refresh the left/primary monitor such as right mouse click or move a screen and (2) The monitor on the right would often rapidly flicker between black and normal.

My friend at work tried to help me install "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updated)" but it resulted in even worse graphical failures (i.e. Google Chrome would graphically (though not functionally) freeze until I resized the window and the right monitor would often just go black until I moved the mouse into its area.

I tried going back to the old driver in (System Settings >> Additional Drivers >> ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver) but the new problems remain.

This is driving me somewhat batty. I don't have any experience in tinkering with Linux drivers. If someone could please help with this issue, I would be extremely grateful.

```
Ubuntu (64-bit):
    $ cat /etc/issue
    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS \n \l

Graphics Card:
    $ lspci -mm | grep VGA
    01:00.0 "VGA compatible controller" "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]" "Turks PRO [Radeon HD 7570]" "Dell" "Device 2b22"
```

I'm perfectly happy to provide any further information necessary to anyone willing to help.

Thanks for your time!